# Remove Selected Value From Drop Down Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to edit data using `Angular` and it works fine. Here what I did is when I edit data, the selected value in `DropDownBox` comes from database. This is also working perfectly. But the issue I am having is the other elements or values of the `DropDownBox` should come along when a default value is selected on edit. So in the front-end, I've something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="number">Number</label>      
    <select class="form-control">
      //Getting selected values here from database
      <option name="Number" [(ngModel)]="value.number" value={{value.number}}>
        {{value.number}}
      </option>

      //Rest of the DropDownBox elements are filled here 
      <option *ngFor="let number of numbers" value={{number.id}}>
        <ng-container *ngIf="number.id != value.number">
          {{number.id}}
        </ng-container>
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In the second section of the HTML section, I tried to remove the repeated value using `ngIf` in DropDownBox and this is what I got now (In this case, 1 is the default value from database along with other values):

[image: DropDownBox Sample]

This actually hides the repeated values as you can there is a space between 1 and 2 containing a blank value (And this is actually the value 1 that gets repeated) that I am trying to get rid of. I was thinking of something as follows to get rid of selected values that repeats in DropDownBox:

```
this.numbers = this.getNumber().filter(item => item.id != id);
```

**numbers** is the variable type of any where I am putting the DropDownBox values but I am not sure how I can pass the selected value on load of Angular. Is there any proper way to do it?

**N.B:** Here is a dummy method for getting numbers

```
getNumber() {
    return [
      new Number(1),
      new Number(2)
   ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be the correct , firt bind the `ngModel` on the select element not the options

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="number">Number</label>      
    <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="value.number">
      <option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number">
          {{number}}
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

> ngModel create a two way data binding is mean if the value.number
>   update this will reflect to the select element and if you update the
>   select elemnt by select different option will update the value.number
>   to that value

update the options

> anytime the `numbers` reference update this will reflect to the
>   options so you don't need to add extra login with **ngIf** just update
>   the `numbers` array and angular will update the options base of that.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdp1ns)

Comment: Got the concept perfectly. Thanks a lot @malbarmawi and if you have time, you can see this one to give a solution. One of my friend's post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824463/how-to-server-side-filtering-pagination-and-sorting-in-jqx-widget-grid-angular-7

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to use two different option tag just learn this code

```
<option *ngFor="let d of cities" value="{{ d.id }}" [selected]="d?.id === cityId">{{
              d?.city_name
            }}</option>
```

in this code in selected property d?.id is code from the API and cityId is what i also got from the API but which is selected by user but in different page..

hope you get your answer.